# slideshow counter disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, counter

I have this code that is supposed to generate a counter for a slideshow and then change the picture and the corresponding number color in the counter.  However, after the slideshow cycles through twice, the counter changes to `display:none` and then reappears and disappears every time the slideshow begins its cycle.

```
//icons for newsreel guide
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("news").length;i++){
    var count=i+1;
    $('#counter').append('<span class="count">'+count+'</span>');
}
//newsreel script
$(".news").hide();
setTimeout (function() {
    var wait = $(".news:last").index()*12000+12000;
    function newsreel(){
    var i=0;
    (function showNews(elem){
        if(i==document.getElementsByClassName("count").length){
            i=0;
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("count")[i].style.color="#000";
        elem.fadeIn(2000,function(){
            elem.delay(8000).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                document.getElementsByClassName("count")[i].style.color="#3159a0";
                i=i+1;
                $(this).next().length && showNews($(this).next()); 
            });
        });
    })
    ( $(".news:first"));
    setTimeout (arguments.callee, wait);
    }/*end newsreel()*/
    newsreel();
}, 2000);
```

At first I thought it was using the deprecated `arguments.callee` but I changed that and it still happens on cue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you use deprecated code?

Comment: @Justin Morgan someone helped me with this slideshow a long time ago and thats what they suggested at the time.

Comment: What is that line doing? `$(this).next().length && showNews($(this).next()); `

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - That line will cause `showNews` to recurse on the later siblings of `$(this)` until it reaches the end of the container.

Comment: Isnt it a conditional term?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - `&&` is short-circuiting in JavaScript, so if `$(this).next().length == 0`, the rest of the statement will never be evaluated and `showNews` won't be called. `showNews` doesn't return anything, so the result of the `&&` expression will be undefined, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, thank for the explaination, learn anything new everyday!

Comment: Well here it work : http://jsfiddle.net/dZdh4/. Isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon I just noticed the fiddle!  I don't know why it works there without a problem but on my website, it has the glitch.  I  think that `#counter` is getting pulled in as part of `elem` and that it's fading out in `elem.delay(8000).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                document.getElementsByClassName("count")[i].style.color="#3159a0";
                i=i+1;
                $(this).next().length && showNews($(this).next()); 
            });`

Comment: Can i see your website? or recreate the problem with a fiddle?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon http://il.water.usgs.gov/adcpnew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, and the problem is in this line :

```
$(this).next().length && showNews($(this).next())
```

`.next()` is getting the next sibling. Your counter is a sibling of `.news`. To solve your problem, do this:

```
$(this).next().length && showNews($(this).next('.news'))
```

That will select the next sibling with the class `news`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because your `showNews` function is never running. I think the JavaScript engine is evaluating

```
(function showNews(elem){
    //...
})
```

and

```
( $(".news:first"));
```

as two different expressions, rather than passing `$(".news:first")` as a parameter to `showNews` as you intend. Since `;` at the end of a line is optional in JS, the parser will insert one automatically if the result is valid JavaScript. In this case, it defines a function but never calls it, then builds a jQuery sequence but never uses it.

Try removing the carriage return between the two:

```
(function showNews(elem){
    //...
})($(".news:first"));
```

Comment: I think you're on to something here.  I tried removing a carriage return and I still got the strange behavior.  Then I tried to add `#counter` and `.count` as parameters after `.news:first` and I got some strange and interesting results. I think this is where I can add something extra to get my `#counter` div to stay visible.

Comment: @user2434247 - What browser are you using? This looks like something that might be parsed differently among browsers, especially given Karl-André Gagnon's comment that the code worked for him.

Comment: I was doing most of my testing in Firefox.  I just tried it in Chrome and it has the same results.  It runs through the slide show right once and then after the first cycle, the counter disappears so maybe they didn't let it run long enough?